# Cipher and decipher string by shifting +1 using pointer

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, encryption

Hi I am stuck while trying to cipher and decipher string using pointer. i need to shift the alphabet by +1. 
example: Hello will be Ifmmp. And i also need to eliminate other characters such as $%^^. so when the string is 'z' +1 would give me 'a'
Here is my code.

```
char *cipher(char *s) {
    int i =0;
    int shift = 1;

    while(*(s+i)!= '\0') {
        if (*(s+i)) {
            *(s+i)+= (shift);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

char *decipher(char *s) {
    int i =0;
    int shift = -1;

    while(*(s+i)!= '\0') {
        if (*(s+i) +shift) {
            *(s+i)+= (shift);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

my current output is:
To cipher: abcxyz -> bcdyz{
To decipher: bcdyz{ -> abcxyz

Thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure that `if (*(s+i) +shift >=65 && (*(s+i)+= shift <=90))` does not do what you want. Note the `*(s+i)+=...`.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem. do you have any idea how i can eliminate other character such as !@#$? @mch

Comment: Take a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`First of all`, change the while to For-Loop, if you increase itearator at the for loop and its your condition the best readable code is For-Loop

`Second`, you need to add condtion- 
`If` the letter is `'z'` assign 'a'
`else` do the same thing

Third if you want to avoide another letters you need to add condition:

```
if((*s+i)<'a' || (*s+i)>'z'){
  do what you want
} else { 
   avoide
} /// it will work if you use character encoding that the alphebet is by order and continuous
```

I add the code with change at chipher function, you will add the same to the next function

```
char *cipher(char *s){
int shift = 1;
for(int i=0; *(s+i)!= '\0'; i++){
  if (*(s+i)){
    //i add that condtion for 'z' you need to add the same condition         to the next function
    if(*(s+i)=='z'){
     *(s+i)='a';
    }else{
    *(s+i)+= (shift);
    }
  }
 }
}

char *decipher(char *s){
   int shift = -1;
   for(int i=0 ;*(s+i)!= '\0'; i++){
     if (*(s+i) +shift){
       *(s+i)+= (shift);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

> i need to shift the alphabet by +1

Shift only characters `a-z`.  So code must detect those

```
char *shift_AZ(char *s, int shift) {
  // Bring shift into 0-25 range
  shift %= 26;
  if (shift < 0) shift += 26;

  // loop until at end of string
  // while(*(s+i)!= '\0') {
  while(*s) {  
    // Assuming ASCII, detect select characters
    if ((*s >= 'a') && (*s <= 'z')) {
      // Do the shift, wrap around via %26
      *s = (*s - 'a' + shift)%26 + 'a';
    }
    s++; // next chraracter
  }

  char *cipher(char *s) {
    return shift_AZ(s, 1);
  }

  char *decipher(char *s) {
    return shift_AZ(s, -1);
  }
```